# How do I download an image/file to a specified location on the disk?

Tags: 7, files

I want to provide the functionality to the users to download the images/files to their system but not with direct download but with a dialog where they tell the location where they want to download the image.

I have tried the [download_file](https://www.drupal.org/project/download_file) and [file_force](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_force) modules. Both modules provide the field formatter to download the image. but when the user click on the download link the the image directly downloads, it does not provide the option to the user to specify a location for the image to be downloaded in.

Is there any other module or any other method?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is largely up to browser itself, and this can't be controlled over how the browser has been configured.

[image: Prompt download settings]

Above settings are from **Google Chrome** browser. If user has checked "*Ask where to save each file before downloading*" checkbox, then browser will prompt to choose location else download to default location set in "*Download Location*".

Instead try educating the user before they download. That's the best way.

Ref : [Prompt user to save file to a specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405229/377342)